# Data Structure which allows child to be the root of the tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to read `ANTLR` Grammar and store it in a data structure. I am facing the problem of choosing the right data structure to store this grammar.
My Grammar is like :-

```
('show' | 'give' | 'get' | 'list') ('me')? ('all')? (XYZ 'of:')? phrase | (XYZ 'of:')? phrase
```

Here 'XYZ' is the child as well as the root for my searching. Which data structure will allow me to treat child as the root ?

Comment: May I suggest using a graph implemented using a linked list for example, would this be helpful for your quest?

Comment: How about creating a root with edges to both `('show' | 'give' | ....)` and `(XYZ...)`? (p.s. `'list' 'me'` is invalid)

Comment: @beaker I have used the root in my graph.It served my purpose.Thanks

Comment: @KhaledHamdy I thought of keeping root as better option rather than having a separate linked list..Thanks for suggestion